# Safari ignores padding-right on inline-block element

Tags: css, safari

I ran into a weird problem with Safari.
It seems to ignore the padding of a link when the span inside is inline-block.
Works in FF and Chrome but Safari just ignores the right padding.

I can add a padding to the span inside but then FF and Chrome have too much space on the right. The structure is generated by the speeddial component in primefaces so not easily changed.

Here's a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBieY.png) of the problem in Safari and Firefox for comparison.

Anyone ran into this problem before?
Thanks in advance!

```css
ul{
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

span{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
svg{
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  max-width: 1.25rem;
  vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>
        <svg enable-background="new 0 0 20 21.4" viewBox="0 0 20 21.4">
          <path d="m13.1 8.4v-6h1v-2h-8.2v2h1v6l-4.4 9.6c-.1.1-.1.3-.1.4v.5c0 .2 0 .4.1.6s.1.4.3.5c.2.3.4.5.7.7.2.2.5.3.9.3h11.2c.3 0 .7-.1 1-.3s.5-.4.7-.7c.2-.3.3-.6.3-1 0-.3 0-.7-.2-1zm-4.2.7c0-.1.1-.2.1-.2 0-.1 0-.1 0-.2v-6.2h2v6.2.2c0 .1 0 .2.1.2l2.1 4.7h-6.4z" fill="#fff"></path>
        </svg>
        Link text one
      </span></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#"><span>
        <svg enable-background="new 0 0 20 21.4" viewBox="0 0 20 21.4">
          <path d="m13.1 8.4v-6h1v-2h-8.2v2h1v6l-4.4 9.6c-.1.1-.1.3-.1.4v.5c0 .2 0 .4.1.6s.1.4.3.5c.2.3.4.5.7.7.2.2.5.3.9.3h11.2c.3 0 .7-.1 1-.3s.5-.4.7-.7c.2-.3.3-.6.3-1 0-.3 0-.7-.2-1zm-4.2.7c0-.1.1-.2.1-.2 0-.1 0-.1 0-.2v-6.2h2v6.2.2c0 .1 0 .2.1.2l2.1 4.7h-6.4z" fill="#fff"></path>
        </svg>
        Link text
      </span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changing  `max-width: 1.25rem;` to  `width: 1.25rem;` should solve the problem. Some browsers are less forgiving if a svg doesn't have any explicit width or height.

Comment: Omg, thats it. Should've thought of that myself. Thanks @herrstrietzel